# Directory Listing Denied This Virtual Directory does not allow contents to be listed

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

While accessing my WordPress website, I got directory listing error. I can access the site using `http://example.com/index.php` but not when I use `http://example.com`. I also tried put the *.htaccess* file in the directory. I had following code in my *.htaccess* file.

```
#BEGIN WordPress
#END WordPress
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: I assume you are using Apache server, is that true?

Comment: this is caused cause of restricted browsing in subfolders. thanxxx for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it... If any want to change your site path not having access to control panel in your db go to the wp-options table change your site url link to http://www.example.com to the http://www.example.com/index.php